# Android project shows error when copying some lines of code to a java file or xml file

Tags: android, eclipse

When I copysome lines of code to java file or xml file there comes an error "R.layout.main cannot be resolved" and "Link all references for a local rename". Why is this happening? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess: Eclipse automatically includes android.R instead of your.project.package.R when you paste the code? Happens to me more often that I'd like to admit.